# Why doesnt any change to the masterpage effect the default landing page of publishing portal?

Tags: master-page, publishing-site

We are using seattle.master. After creating a publishing portal site colelction, we modified the masterpage and added text 'test' right after starting body tag.

However, it wont appear in the default landing page of publishing portal site. Why is this?
It does appear on other pages of the site.

What is the way out? Also we notice that it is not possible to edit and add webaprts to the default landing page.